# How can I search for an App in the ITunes App Store in a webbrowser

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

I would like to search for an app in the apples app store in a webbrowser, if this is possible. I know it is possible by installing Itunes, but I don't like to do that and I hope, that it is not needed to do a simple search for an App. This way I could send a link of an URL to someone to show the app.
Is this possible? In GooglePlay it is so simple and intuitiv, but in the MAC-World I am lost again with such a simple request.

I know, that the app exists, because I wrote it myself and I can find it with the "App Store" - App on my IPad, so I am sure it exists.

Would be happy if someone would guide me to this search-feature, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes has a search API as documented [here](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/), you don't need to use Google. To search for apps only, set `entity` to `software`. If you want to call this from your website via JavaScript, you'll probably also need to set `callback` to something appropriate.

Here is an example search URL which will return results for apps with "myApp" `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=MyApp&entity=software`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google and the `site:` scheme.

As an example, you could type in the search engine:

```
site:itunes.apple.com sleep
```

This will list all the apps from the `itunes.apple.com` site that contain the keyword `sleep`.

Comment: So there is no official search site from apple like GooglePlay with Android. By the way, I can't find my App with the exact naming.

Comment: When did you submit your app ? Because there may be a latency between the time you submitted it and the time it is visible, or even referenced by Google. Wait for a while and may be you app will appear

Comment: Its published 3 weeks ago. So the answer is No, thats not possible in the MACs world, right ? Simply searching an app. In Itunes I can find it.

Comment: As Apple validates each app, it may be that long but I trully do not know this information. Asking Apple support could be useful

Comment: No, Thats not possible. The app is published and ready and friends purchased already. But of course, when there is no possibility to search the appstore in a browser directly, then its not sure that searchresult are actual. I just can't believe that there is no way to query for an app in a browser without installing a software. Its so stoneage like. I mean if you like to show an app to a friend, how can you tell this by email, when you can't provide any link or so.

Comment: You can if you have the link to your app via itunes.apple.com. What is the name of you app and the name of the editor (your name) ? I will make a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37158/discussion-between-lauhub-and-user1344545).

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is not correct. Apple offers a search API for the AppStore, which gives a lot more information in machine readable format. Why anyone would want to use a google search is beyond me.

Comment: Thank you @JustSid. I did not know this and tried to help with my abilities.

Answer (score 0):

To get a link, there is a way.
- Go into Itunes
- Click on the apps popdown and choose "create a link"
Then you get something like :
https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/APPNAME/id1078891695?mt=8
this can be sent

Very frustrating, that there is no way to get this link without ITunes. Mac is unuserfriendly !